# How to vertically center a <p> inside an <a>

Tags: html, css

sorry to bug you all.

I cant work this out and it hurting my brain.

I have a `<a>` tag and inside that is a `<p>` and `<img>`.
I want to have the contents of the `<p>` vertically centered on the image when I hover over the image.

[image: image goes here]

Please find my html and css below.

Thanks again

```css
    html,
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      /*Text Selection cancelled - unable to select text*/
      -webkit-touch-callout: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -khtml-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    #profpic {
      opacity: 0;
      transition: 1s;
    }
    table {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
    .user {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center center;
      background-size: cover;
      background-image: url('sir.png');
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
      -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
      transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
    }
    .user:hover {
      opacity: 0.6;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      -webkit-opacity: 0.25;
      -moz-opacity: 0.25;
      opacity: 0.25;
    }
    #a-tag {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    #a-tag #profpic {
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      text-align: center;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin: 0;
      color: #fff;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: 1s;
    }
    #a-tag:hover #profpic {
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Create User in Database</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="adduser.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="Raspberry_Pi.png">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="signup">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <form action="addrecord.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="username" value="Username">
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="fullname" value="Fullname">
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="Email Address">
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="password" value="Password">
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
        </th>
        <th>
          <!-- Something to choose a profile picture -->

          <a id="a-tag" href="#">
            <p id="profpic">choose Profile Pic</p>
            <img class="user" src="sir.png" height="190" width="190">
          </a>

        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    }); // end document.ready
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's **not valid** for the `p` (block element) to be inside the `a` (inline element)

Comment: what do i use instead Vucko ?

Comment: Use `span` and style to suit your needs.

Comment: @Vucko you can use block element inside inline element in html5

Comment: @Morpheus I didn't say that you can't, I said that it's not valid.

Comment: @Vucko It's perfectly valid according to the doctype used (HTML 5) according to REC from W3C, see [the a element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) (edit: it's not an _%inline_ element anymore, it's far more complicated). It wasn't in HTML 4.1 and XHTML 1.0. It may not be accessible or well understood by assistive technologies like screen readers though

Comment: @FelipeAls then I stand corrected. Thanks for the references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add some padding to the `#profpic` id like so

```
#a-tag:hover #profpic{
padding-top:95px;
opacity:1;
}
```

Here's a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adityamantha/L1r1qqx8/)

Answer (score 2):

'a' is an inline element while 'p' is a block element and 'img' is an inline-block element. That means an 'a' element won't have its "height" attribute unless you specific it as a 'block' element.

you can try this:

```
    #a-tag{display:block; height:190px; line-height:190px;}
    #a-tag img{width:190px; height:190px;}
```

Answer (score -1):

set position absolute to p and justify it by top and left. u can have one class to cage the p by setting position relative

```css
p{
  position:absolute;
  top:200px;
  left:200px;
}
```